# Hide a button on a view from an other view iphone sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, sdk, hide

I have 2 Views, the first named "InterfaceController", and second named "LoginController".
On LoginController, I have a button "Connexion", and I want when I click on this one, I'd like the button I called "TEST" be hidden.

So I tried : 
Interfacecontroller.h :

```
@interface InterfaceController : UIViewController {
- (IBAction)TEST:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)LoginSwitch:(id)sender;
}
```

Logincontroller.h :

```
@interface LoginController : UIViewController {
}
- (IBAction)Connexion:(id)sender;
@end
```

Logincontroller.m :

```
#import "InterfaceController.h"
#import "LoginController.h"
@implementation LoginViewController

- (IBAction)Connexion:(id)sender {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
        InterfaceController.TEST.hidden = YES; (this is what I want to set)
}
```

.........

I don't really know how to do this, but I think it's easy.
Somebody can explain me ?

Comment: where is the TEST button declaration ?!!
and those are 2 viewcontrollers not just 2 ,, and in order to access methods or properties you need a delegate,,, see this question
[HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658433/accessing-method-from-other-classes-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an outlet of test button in interfaceController.h:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIButton *TEST;
```

after that in Interface Builder you have to link this Outlet to the Test Button.

At this point your code works