# How to access function in another class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to ios.I have a class which carries all attributes and methods.I am intending to access that class content one json method which parses the data.Now, I have another class. I want to call json method in that class.Plz tell how can i achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried to google your question?

Comment: yes didnt get the right answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731126/how-to-call-method-from-one-class-in-another-ios and you may check the **Related** questions right of the this answer ;).

Answer (score 4):

If the method is class (i.e. static) method:

```
[NameOfClass methodName:parameter];
```

If the method is instance method:

```
[instanceOfClass methodName:parameter];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make you method public.
to Do so add declaration of you method to .h file.

Like so:

```
-(void) myJSONMethod;
```

Answer (score 0):

here is reference [Accessing Method from other Classes Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658433/accessing-method-from-other-classes-objective-c)

```
@implementation commonClass
+ (void)CommonMethod:(id)sender  /* note the + sign */
{
//So some awesome generic stuff...
    }
@end

@implementation ViewController2

- (void)do_something... {
    [commonClass CommonMethod];
}


@end
```

Option 2:

```
@implementation commonClass
- (void)CommonMethod:(id)sender
{
//So some awesome generic stuff...
    }
@end

@implementation ViewController2

- (void)do_something... {
    commonClass *c=[[commonClass alloc] init];
    [c CommonMethod];
    [c release];
}

@end
```

Option 3: use inheritance (see Mr. Totland's description in this thread)

```
@implementation commonClass
- (void)CommonMethod:(id)sender
{
//So some awesome generic stuff...
    }
@end
```

/* in your .h file */

```
@interface ViewController2: commonClass

@end
```

naturally you always need to #import commonClass.h in your view controllers..

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an object for your second class. By using this object, you can call methods that you declared in the second class header file.

```
ClassName *obj = [[ClassName alloc]init];
[obj methodName];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have to call a class method

```
[ClassName methodName:parameter];
```

if you have instance method

```
 ClassName * obj = [[ClassName alloc] init];

 [obj methodName:parameter];
```

but make sure that , you have declared that method in ClassName.h file also .