# Why isn't my method calling?

Tags: objective-c, methods, viewcontroller

Hi I am trying to call a method from another class and it is not working.

Here is the method I want to call, "updateName".

```
@interface Content1ViewController ()

@end

@implementation Content1ViewController

+ (void)updateName:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"IT WORKED");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

@end
```

Then I try call it in a method from another class.

```
-(void)randomMethod {

[Content1ViewController updateName];

}
```

Then I get a error at "update name" as it doesn't recognise the method? I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658433/accessing-method-from-other-classes-objective-c) and its not working for me. I have made sure I have imported the classes to each other aswell.

Can someone please tell me why its not working? Thanks.

Comment: Have you declared + (void)updateName:(id)sender; in your .h file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you declare the method in header file of `Content1ViewController`, that will make it public. Also, the signature of the caller method is different as of Originally declared method. The `updateName` is expecting a parameter of `(id)sender`, Make sure you pass it some reference to call the right method.

Answer (score 0):

Here updateName is a method with sender as a parameter.

```
[Content1ViewController updateName:SOME_SENDER_ID_INSTANCE]; //Should work. Because your method definition says it needs `id` as param.
```

Answer (score 0):

updateName has got a parameter sender and you are not passing it while calling the method and hence you are getting error

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration doesn't match the method signature i.e. you need to call:

```
[Content1ViewController updateName:SOMETHING_HERE];
```